# Searching values from a parameter file

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a scenario in my mapping wherein I have a parameter file with a variable, say `$$param_var='a,b,c,d,e'`.

I need to compare this variable with my input data, i.e. if the input data is equal to any of the values present in the variable then perform a certain task. For example, if the input data=`$$param_var` and input data=a or b or c or d or e then do something.

I tried using the `instr` function provided by Informatica provided and `IN` but it didn't solve the issue. Neither of these worked:

```
INSTR(input_port,$$param_value)

INSTR(input_port,'$$param_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable as an expression variable. Select the checkbox IsExprVar in the parameters and variables window in Designer.